# Kotlin failing to decode Base64 string encoded with MySQL's TO_BASE64 function

Tags: mysql, email, kotlin, base64, aes

I've been tasked with sending a string from a database on one server via a potentially insecure channel (the body text of an email - this is a hard requirement) to another in a different environment. In order to do this safely, I've devised a method by which the string is compressed, encrypted with AES, converted to base64 to prevent the email system mangling it and then this process is reversed on the other end. In order to produce the encrypted and encoded strings, these MySQL functions are used (I'm not bothering with the compression step for now):

```
set @foo = aes_encrypt('foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz', 'AN_AES_KEY');
set @bar = to_base64(convert(@foo using ascii)); /* this is what's sent via email */
```

The receiver program is written in Kotlin and has to reverse each of these steps then write the result to a database. Unfortunately, I appear to be falling at the first hurdle. I've tried many base64 decoding options and frustratingly none of them reproduce the AES ciphertext that I'd then decrypt with my key. I've noticed the following behaviour as I change the decoding function:

- Each function produces nonsense output that doesn't match the AES ciphertext.
- Each function produces the correct number of bytes (IE the same as the ciphertext)

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using static variables. The encryption & base64-encoding on MySql-side is:

```
ibGlUpmQMyIxSOomWRbejfCyE637P8ViPFDi5AlRNmaUyHenwtCYD79rdCSYg8ur
```

Using this as input for Kotlin:

```
import java.util.Base64
...
val fromSql: String = "ibGlUpmQMyIxSOomWRbejfCyE637P8ViPFDi5AlRNmaUyHenwtCYD79rdCSYg8ur"
val decodedBytes: ByteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(fromSql)
```

You can use `decodedBytes` as direct input for your Kotlin AES ECB-decryption method.

When decrypting this input with the key `AN_AES_KEY` you will get the original input back on Kotlin-side:

```
output: foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz
```